# Root mount error while upgrading from ubuntu 10.10 to 11.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10

I had an electricity cut while I was upgrading from Ubuntu 10.10 to 11.04, now when booting the system I get the following message:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

At the grub boot menu if you type <kbd>e</kbd> to `edit` the grub configuration for the line you've selected you'll see a line something like this:

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-12-generic root=UUID=ddbfffc1-731c-4931-9129-75c5f42f8ecb ro single nomodeset
```

The culprit is the `root=UUID=ddbfffc1-731c-4931-9129-75c5f42f8ecb` part which probably still has the old UUID or partition listed. If you know the specific partition you can either set it to something like `root=/dev/sda1` (or whatever your partition number is) and then type <kbd>ctrl-x</kbd> to boot or you can substitute the correct UUID which you can find by booting with a rescue disk and running the `blkid` command.

If you're lucky and your root partition has been properly labeled then you could also try `root=LABEL=/`.

Answer (score 0):

this goes after grub? 
if yes - you can change yours grub settings  for hd and init=/bin/sh and run something like fsck

Comment: Can you explain more? as a start it says: The disk drive / is not ready yet or not present, but when i go to console, I can access all files

Comment: how you access that files? 
you can try to check blkid /etc/mtab and grub configuration if UIDS are correct.

Comment: I went with the recovery mode and it said it can't mount drives then it gave me the console. Using it I can access files with no problems. Not sure what to do with the commands u specified above.

Comment: can you show yours `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and command `/sbin/blkid ` result?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once, way back with... I think it was Ubuntu 7. The Disk UUID's changed, I can't remember why.

I mounted manually, edited /etc/fstab and replaced the UUID entries with actual partitions (eg: /dev/sda1, /dev/sda2 and so on) and rebooted.

Comment: I am sorry to say that I have the same problem. But, unfortunately, comment from Some Guy couldn't help me because the UUID value in fstab actually matches the output of blkid. BTW I tried to use /dev/sda1 instead of the uuid, but it didn't help.